# How to capture only first occurence in this regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string:

```
2+*+2+*+3+*+3+*
```

And this regex:

```
(\d{1,3}\+\*\+\d{1,3})
```

Problem is, it captures both matches (2+*+2 and 3+*+3), and I need it to capture only the first occurence.

How can I change my regex to match this?

Here's the regex101 url for anyone who wants to try:

https://regex101.com/r/7G2adU/1/

Thanks!!

Comment: How are you using the regex ? You don't have to take all matches. Show your javascript code.

Comment: Just turn off the global flag, and only the first match will be returned

Comment: @CertainPerformance dear god, sometimes I dwell on stuff, and totally forget the simple stuff :/

Please write it as an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your regex to:

```
^(\d{1,3}\+\*\+\d{1,3})
```

then only the first match will be captured. The caret `^` is a start-of-string anchor; it matches the start of the input string so that only the first occurrence of the rest of the regex is captured.

There is another alternative. In your example https://regex101.com/r/7G2adU/1/ your regex looks like this:

```
/(\d{1,3}\+\*\+\d{1,3})/ig
```

The `g` is the global flag; it tells the engine not to stop after the first match has been found, but rather to continue until no more matches can be found. If you remove that flag, only the first match will be returned.

Comment: Thanks, I was waiting for CaptainPerformance to write his comment as an answer, but he didn't so I'll accept yours instead :)